# Nested for loop improvements

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a program with an array of **maximum 63** places. The user specifies the actual active places of the array which all have a starting value of 0.

I want to:
Scan through the active places of the array and in the places positioned at : 0+4*n and 3+4*n (where n=0,1,2,3,4, ((total-5)/4) check if the value is 0 and if yes make it 1.
For the last 5 active places of the array that were not included in the previous search, i will just check the first and the last of the five places of the array. If the value is 0 make it 1. 
In all cases i only want to change **only one value**  at a time. If a zero is found then give a value of 1 and then stop. 
If no values of the above are 0 -> have an error message.

**My problem is in the last part with the error message** that starts running when other if statements activate..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int array[63];
    int i,n,total;
    char selection;

    for (i=0; i<63; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
    printf("Enter active array places (maximum 63):");
    scanf(" %d",&total);

    do{
        printf("0.Exit \n");
        printf("1.List array \n");
        printf("2.Change value of array: \n");
        scanf(" %c",&selection);

        if (selection=='1')
            {   
                for (i=0; i<total; i++)
                    printf("%d \n", array[i]);
            }

        else if (selection=='2')
            {
                for (i=0; i<(total); i++)
                    {
                    if ((i%4==0) && i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
                                    {
                                        array[i]=1;
                                        printf("You changed array value in place %d, ",i);

                                        break;
                                    }


                                else if ((i%4==3)&&i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
                                    {
                                        array[i]=1;
                                        printf("You changed array value in place %d, ",i);

                                        break;
                                    }
                                else if (i==(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
                                    {
                                        array[i]=1;
                                        fprintf("You changed array value in place %d, ",i);
                                        i=n=total+1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                else if (i==(total-1)&&(array[i]==0))
                                    {
                                        array[i]=1;
                                        printf("You changed array value in place %d, ",i);
                                        i=n=total+1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                else
                                    printf("Nothing to change");

                            }
                    }
            }
    } while (selection!='0');
}
```

Comment: You don't need nested loops. Just check if `i%4 == 0 || i%4 == 3`

Comment: Thanks! I improved my code with your suggestion, as seen above. However the main problem which is the last else statement remains..i think i am close to the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit more complicated than need (see comment from @Barmar).

However, if we use your code as it is currently, one way to handle the error message is to take the print out of the loop and use a variable to remember whether something was changed.

Something like:

```
int item_changed = 0;  // In the start of the code before the for-loop
```

and

```
if ((i%4==0) && i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
{
    array[i]=1;
    printf("You changed array value in place %d, ",i);
    item_changed = 1; // Add this in all 4 places where you change the array
    break;
}
```

Remove this part

```
else
    printf("Nothing to change");
```

and put this after the for-loop.

```
if (item_changed == 0)
    printf("Nothing to change");
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It worked. I had to make a small minor adjustment to your solution.. Just in the start of the for loop i added item_changed=0; so that the item_changed variable, resets to 0 each time a for loop starts!